# MPI_Sendrecv vs combination of MPI_Isend and MPI_Recv

Tags: mpi

Recently I saw in a book on computational physics that the following piece of code was used to shift data across a chain of processes:

```
MPI_Isend(data_send, length, datatype, lower_process, tag, comm, &request);
MPI_Recv(data_receive, length, datatype, upper_process, tag, comm, &status);
MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
```

I think the same can be achieved by a single call to `MPI_Sendrecv` and I don't think there is any reason to believe the former is faster. Does it have any advantages?

Comment: You should use `MPI_Sendrecv()` to make the code easier to read/maintain. Plus it gives the MPI implementer the opportunity to make small optimizations (and hence make it faster than the `isend/recv/wait` variant). Since most of the time is generally spent waiting for the message, do not expect significant performance improvements though. FWIW, you generally want to avoid unexpected messages as much as possible (they can cause some memory allocation and slow down everything) so posting the `MPI_Irecv()` first is wiser than starting with `MPI_Isend()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, By "unexpected messages" in your last sentence, you mean send posts for which no matching receives are already posted?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I'm wondering if it is possible to post `MPI_Irecv()` first in case 'probing' is needed (unknown incoming message size). Unlike `MPI_Irecv()`, `MPI_Iprobe` doesn't make a request object.

Comment: you cannot `MPI_Irecv()` if you do not know an upper bound for the incoming message size. I would avoid `MPI_Isend(); MPI_Probe(); MPI_Recv()` because it definitely involves unexpected messages under the hood.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, No, I don't have an upper bound. I can either use a separate communication to get the size of the next message or use `MPI_Probe()`. I have no idea which is faster in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no real difference between the fragment you give and an `MPI_sendrecv` call. The `sendrecv` combo is fully compatible with regular sends and receives: you could for instance when shifting data through a (non-periodic!) chain use `sendrecv` everywhere but the end points, and do a regular `send/isend/recv/irecv` there.

You can think of two variants on your code fragment: use a `Isend/Recv` combination or use `Isend/Irecv`. There are probably minor differences in how these are treated in the underlying protocols, but I wouldn't worry about them.

Your fragment can of course more easily be generalized to other patterns than shifting along a chain, but if you have indeed a setup where each process sends to at most one and receives from at most one, then I'd use `MPI_Sendrecv` just for cleanliness. This one just makes the reader wonder: "is there a deep reason for this".

Comment: Seemingly, `MPI_Sendrecv` can be used at the end points as well, because `MPI_PROC_NULL` can be used as destination/source there.

Comment: @apadana Oh, absolutely. I let that one go without mention because I was focusing on the interoperability of sendrecv & send / recv, but yes, you're right.